# Rails 4 NoMethodError in SessionsController#create undefined method `slice' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

my sessions controller

```
       class SessionsController < ApplicationController
         def create
         user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])

         session[:user_id] = user.id
         redirect_to root_url
        end

       def destroy
           session[:user_id] = nil
           redirect_to root_url
        end
            end
```

my user.rb

```
      class User < ActiveRecord::Base

       def self.from_omniauth(auth)
             where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
           user.provider = auth.provider
           user.uid = auth.uid
           user.name = auth.info.name
           user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
           user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
           user.save!
     end
  end
```

end
can anyone show me the cause of an error i search on S.O for the same but not able to find relevant solution
end

Comment: what are you expecting your `env["omniauth.auth"]` variable is holding...

Comment: You're calling `#slice` on `auth`, and `auth` is nil. Your omniauth hash is coming out nil.

Comment: i want my face book authentication

Comment: First check the value of `auth` using `raise auth.inspect`

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue

self.from_omniauth  try to create new user , so i got the validation error  Email can't be left blank or username can't be left blank, so comment your validation and try .

use rails model  scenario in model   "on"=>"create" ,    "on"=>"update"  in your validation